# iphone uitableviewcell - mulitiple colors in the same cell textLabel?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your name: %@", yourName];
```

I need yourName to appear in red (while "your name" stays the default black color). Possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create 2 `UILabel`s, one containing the 'your name' and the second `UILabel` has the variable. The first has a textcolour of black and the second is red

Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) for creating custom `UITableViewCell`s

Comment: You could also just create and add the UILabels dynamically when you are drawing the cell. Less work, just need to lay it out in code instead of IB